# How can I improve my model for a vocabulary list?

Tags: java

I am programming a small **vocabulary viewer** in Java. You can

- add vocabulary to a language
- switch between languages
- see an overview for each language (with many vocabulary)
- watch vocabulary in detail

The interesting thing is that I want to display the translation for **all languages** if a vocabulary has been added in many languages (I know that this can lead to wrong connections in terms of linguistics, but it’s just for training my Java skills anyway).

Currently I have the following classes:

- `VocabularyList (Observable)`, which is just a list implementation for many `<Vocabulary>` with additional methods for retrieving by language etc. This list is observed by all my overview page, when something in this list changes, it refreshes the view.
- `Vocabulary` which uses `HashMap<Language, ArrayList<String>> meanings` to save all meanings **in all languages** (so e.g. I could say that *helfen* in German means the same as *help* or *aid* in English).
- `Language` which is only a class for representing a language (by ISO code and name)

I also store everything in the **same serialization file** at the moment. I would like serialization instead of database to keep the whole thing easy.

However, I have the feeling that this model is totally wrong, because:

- I cannot access vocabulary for each languages separately (even though I have a selection field for the language in my program), so I have to iterate through the whole list each time the user watches the overview page
- I always carry the overhead for all languages around even if somebody only watches the overview (and not a detail page with translations for all languages)

However, I do not really know how I should implement it better, if I want to keep the relation between all different vocabulary languages.

The next idea is:

- Create one vocabulary list for **each** language

But then the whole relationship stuff would be difficult. E.g. if I deleted a vocabulary from the *Russian list* I would have to delete all links to it from all other language lists.

What model design would you suggest? Am I totally of the way or is it already somehow correct? As web developer I have only worked with databases all the time (mostly relational), where in such a case I would just have to delete an entry in a many-to-many relationship table. But when working with objects everything seems different.